# How to add foreign keys, references and indexes for comments

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a column like:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thread_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

- id - uniq comment identifier
- thread_id - thread of that comment
- parent_id - comment that is parent to this comment

Now, there can be two types of comments in that table. One that is the comment to the main thread (thread_id is not null in that case), and comment to comment (thread_id is null and parent_id is not null in that case). I would like to create an INDEX for thread_id and parent_id for optimization, and foreign keys and references so that if:

1. moderator deletes main thread, all comments to that thread and possible comments to comments will be deleted as well, recursively
2. moderator deletes some comment within main thread, that comment and its childs will be also deleted, recursively

If child will be deleted, no action, as nothing "below".

I tried smth like this:

```
 INDEX (parent_id, thread_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, thread_id)
    REFERENCES (id)
```

But not sure if it's ok, as working on the same table confuses me a bit.

Comment: So, what is your problem here?

Comment: I'd use an example of how to do it effectively, tried few things but for some of the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I was thinking about smth like INDEX (parent_id, thread_id), FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, thread_id) REFERENCES (id), but not sure if it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to create the first one that works:

```
CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`thread_id`) 
    REFERENCES `threads` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now when I delete thread, comments of that thread gets deleted as well.

But I stuck on making foreign key within the same table between id and parent_id, for comments and replies to comments, any idea?

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`database`.`#sql-a4f_3796`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-a4f_3796_ibfk_2` 
FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Tried both directions, switching parent_id and id, no effects.

Comment: Don't ask questions in answer posts. Is this even an answer to the question post? If so please edit out the part that isn't an answer. If it's not an answer but a change to the question post, delete this & edit the question post. [answer] [ask] [Help]